# How do I capture/view the post-request generated by my browser on submission of a form?

Tags: html, forms

So the system I'm working on is using a complicated process to generate and display HTML forms, and an even more complicated process to handle these forms once submitted.

I want to be able to cut through the abstraction and just view, in plain text, the post-request that is generated by my browser when I hit 'Submit' on the form - the headers, the payload, everything - How can I do this? If there's a tool to make it easier to pick through, all the better, but if I can just get it in plain text that's fine too!

I realize this might seem like a very basic question, but I've actually never needed it before.

Thanks!

Comment: Though, the recent browsers has these functionalities in-built, I still prefer to use Fiddler.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using chrome hit F12 before submitting form,
 then go to network tab -> Check Preserve log checkbox, and then hit the submit button, you can see the detail of your post request

Comment: That's great! Is there any way to view it just as plain XML? I can view it parsed and unparsed, but it still doesn't look how I imagine a raw POST-request to look...

Comment: Inbuilt browser provides only this functionality. Try some extensions of chrome like 
[Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)